# Autocomplete username but not password in IE

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there a way to have autocomplete turned on for usernames, but have it off
for passwords in IE ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you ask about ASP.NET application, in this case maybe  you can use the jquery javascript framework, they have a plugin named [Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) and you can activate for any control you want.